# mkdir() skips first file in foreach function

Tags: php

I have a script which reads a URL-Image-List and saves the images in a folder which based on the URL.

[image: This is how it should look like]

Here is my script:

```
// Open the URL and save each line in a array
$file = fopen("http://www.edem.de/php/imglist.ashx","r");
$fileArray = array();
while (($line = fgetss($file)) !== false) {
    $fileArray[] = $line;
}

// Sort the array
array_multisort(array_values($fileArray), SORT_NUMERIC , array_keys($fileArray), SORT_NUMERIC , $fileArray);

// Start the iteration for saving each image
foreach ($fileArray as $url) {

    // Explode URL for folder and image name
    $urlpath = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $dataend = explode("/", $urlpath);
    $ending = $dataend[5];
    $folder = $dataend[3];

    // delete "_" and "whitespace"
    $folder = strtr($folder, "_", " ");
    $folder = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $folder);
    $ending = strtr($ending, "_", " ");
    $ending = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $ending);

    // Check if folder exist. If yes -> go on with path. If no -> create folder
    if (!file_exists("Bilder/$folder/")) {
        $imgpath = mkdir("Bilder/$folder/", 0777, true);
        //I THINK THE MISTAKE IS HERE
    }
    else {
        $imgpath = ('Bilder/' .$folder. '/');
    }

    // save the path and the image name in a variable
    $savepath = $imgpath . $ending;

    // Test echo
    echo ("The image <strong>$ending</strong> is saved in the folder <strong>$savepath</strong>. The file should be in the folder <strong>$folder</strong><br><br>");    

    //Connect and save images
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $fp = fopen(''.$savepath.'','w');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Each folder should contain a few images.
BUT: When the folder has to be created, he creates this folder but save the first image in root and not in this folder.

**Example echo**
[image: Here is the created echo of this script]
The folder get created but the first image doesn't save in this new folder.
The following images which also belong to this folder, get saved correctly.

I get no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this first case, you are storing it as `true` or `false`. Change the following:

```
// Check if folder exist. If yes -> go on with path. If no -> create folder
if (!file_exists("Bilder/$folder/")) {
    $imgpath = mkdir("Bilder/$folder/", 0777, true);
    //I THINK THE MISTAKE IS HERE
}
else {
    $imgpath = ('Bilder/' .$folder. '/');
}
```

To:

```
// Check if folder exist. If yes -> go on with path. If no -> create folder
if (!file_exists("Bilder/$folder/")) {
    mkdir("Bilder/$folder/", 0777, true);
}
$imgpath = ('Bilder/' .$folder. '/');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$imgpath = mkdir(....
```

http://docs.php.net/mkdir says:

**Return Values**

Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Sorry I dont get, what you want me to tell.

Comment: That it doesnt return the final path. So you are trying to save the image to a value = TRUE or FALSE. Not for example bilder/###/###.jpg

Comment: In another words, if it could create the dir, it will throw TRUE, else will give you FALSE, but won't give you the path

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code:

```
if (!file_exists("Bilder/$folder/")) {
    $imgpath = mkdir("Bilder/$folder/", 0777, true);
    //I THINK THE MISTAKE IS HERE
}
else {
    $imgpath = ('Bilder/' .$folder. '/');
}
```

to:

```
if (!is_dir("Bilder/$folder/")) {
    if( ! mkdir("Bilder/$folder/", 0777, true) ){
        continue; // continue = Jump to next. Alternative would be break; which breaks the loop. If it cant create the dir, then you cant upload the file. So I would personally use break; But continue atleast lets you try for all the files.
    }
    $imgpath = "Bilder/{$folder}/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the mkdir manual, the function returns a boolean. Should be true if the directory was created successfully.

> bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )